# Filtering a UITableView based on an NSPredicate from an NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to filter objects in a `UITableView`, which gets its data from a Core Data sqlite via a`NSFetchedResultsController`. It's working fine before filtering, but now I need to be able to tap a button and have it display only objects one of whose properties (a `BOOL`) is `YES`. Lets call it `isFavourite`.

I'm a little confused as to where to begin. I understand the concept of a predicate, and I've constructed this one, which should work:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"isFavourite == 1"];
```

However, I'm a little confused as to how to attach that predicate to the `NSFetchedResultsController`. I already allocated and initialised it, using a separate fetch request which simply returned all objects of that entity (and that works perfectly). If it's been initialised already, can I change its fetch request? If so, how do I do that, then how do I make it re-run the query. Do I then need to manually update the `UITableView` with `reloadData` or similar. Then, what do I do when I want to switch this filter off and go back to viewing all results?

I've read a lot of existing questions here but most seem to relate to search bars, which make the answers a lot more complicated. I've also read the Apple documentation, but tend to find its written in a pretty cryptic fashion. My code is below, I'm only part-way through the `filterFavourite` method and that's where I'm looking for help and clarification.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Quote" inManagedObjectContext: [[CoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"quoteID" ascending: YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize: 50];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest managedObjectContext: [[FQCoreDataController sharedCoreDataController] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath: nil cacheName: nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (IBAction) filterFavourite: (id) sender
{
    if (isDisplayingFavourite) {
        // Switch to showing all..
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"isFavourite == 1"];

        isDisplayingFavourite = NO;
    } else {
        // Switch to showing favourites only..

        isDisplayingFavourite = YES;
    }

}
```

EDIT: The delegate method "`controllerDidChangeContent`" is never called in this code. I can't figure out why that is, either. Hugely, hugely confusing, Core Data is like a brick wall. In fact, NONE of the four delegate methods are ever called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't attach a predicate to the `NSFetchedResultsController`-- you attach it to the `NSFetchRequest`. It has a method called `setPredicate:` that does exactly what its name suggests.

You can modify the fetch request by updating the `fetchRequest` attribute and calling `performFetch:` again. You could also nil out your `fetchedResultsController` ivar, and make the code above flexible enough to add whatever predicate(s) would be useful. The next time your `fetchedResultsController` method is called, it will create a new instance for you with the current predicate(s). That consolidates all of your `NSFetchedResultsController` code in one method. It's probably slightly more expensive in CPU usage but also probably easier to maintain.

Comment: So when I've finished with it, wherever I used it first, I should `nil` it out, then when I come to use it somewhere else, I should make a new `NSFetchRequest` with a predicate, then call `performFetch` on it again?

Comment: I would modify the `fetchedResultsController` to add the predicate when necessary, and then just nil out the instance variable. You can keep all the code for creating the fetched results controller in one method if you make it just a little more flexible than it is right now.

Comment: @TomHarrington: I agree that your answer describes the best solution. - But I have a question concerning your remark *"There's no way to change the fetch request on an NSFetchedResultsController"*. The NSFetchedResultsController documentation has a section "Modifying the Fetch Request" which describes how to set a new fetch request for the FRC. So you cannot modify the existing fetch request (i.e. change the predicate), but you could assign a new fetch request to the existing FRC. Is that correct?